# Where is the heat loss occuring in the Carnot cycle, if compared to a ideal gas turbine

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, heat-engine, carnot-cycle

The most efficient heat engine cannot be more efficient than this (1 - tc/th) so let's assume a hypothetical gas turbine where there is no friction or conduction losses , say the ambient temp is 300k , the air is compressed and then heat is added at constant pressure which increases the temp to let's say 1500kelvin if the turbine is perfect at extracting work and the exhaust gas is very close to ambient temperature and pressure, which should in theory make the turbine (1 - 301/1500) 80% efficient, which means 20% energy is lost , my question is where exactly in the system is the energy lost? Is it the compression ? is it the exhaust , if it's the exhaust then how come there no significant change in the exhaust temp? Or anything else that I am missing

Comment: In your turbine, what mechanism brings the exhaust pressure *and* temperature to ambient?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "heat loss" in the Carnot cycle. In the engine performing an ideal Carnot cycle the engine absorbs a certain amount of entropy $\Delta S$ at a constant temperature $T_h$, the temperature of the entropy reservoir, and expels the *same* amount of entropy into a *lower* constant temperature entropy sink at $T_c$. As said entropy drops from $T_h$ to $T_c$ it performs work $(T_h-T_c)\Delta S$.

This work is performed in an analogous manner to, say, a mass $\Delta m$ having fallen from a gravitational potential $\phi_h$ to a lower gravitational potential $\phi_c$, $(\phi_h-\phi_c)\Delta m$, or an electric charge $\Delta e$ is being dropped from a higher electric potential $\psi_h$ to a lower one, $\psi_c$.

For historical reasons, it is customary to call the "heat" $Q_h$ absorbed at the higher temperature it being the higher thermal potential, $Q_h=T_h\Delta S$, and the rejected "heat" at the lower thermal potential, $Q_c=T_c \Delta S$, but the working agent is not "heat" but "entropy", just as the product of gravitational potential and mass is not the working agent but mass is.